# mod_rewrite hide URL GET parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

Trying to hide the GET parameter URL domain.com/users/edit.php?id=1234 using mod_rewrite so the URL will turn out like this domain.com/users/1234

I tried the mod_rewrite below but doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$ /?id=$1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$ users/edit.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$ /users/edit.php?id=$1
```

Comment: browsers don't cache .htaccess

Comment: How browser caches the .htaccess? you means server caches?

Comment: My mistake, they don't. Browsers only cache things like redirects.